# Getting Header information with RXJava and Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I'm trying to convert my app which currently uses Retrofit, to use RX Java.
In order to handle Pagination, I traditionally was grabbing the nextPage URL from the response headers.

```
@Override
    public void success(Assignment assignment, Response response) {
        response.getHeaders(); // Do stuff with header info
}
```

However, since switching to RX Java, i'm not sure how to get the response information from my retrofit call.

```
   @GET("/{item_id}/users")
    Observable<List<Objects>> getObjects(@Path("object_id") long object_id);

    @GET("/{next}")
    Observable<List<Objects>> getNextPageObjects(@Path("next") String nextURL);
```

Is there a way to have my retrofit calls to return my header information along with my Typed objects?

Answer (score 16):

You can use

```
Observable<Response>
```

as return type to get the response details

```
@GET("/{item_id}/users")
Observable<Response> getObjects(@Path("object_id") long object_id);

@GET("/{next}")
Observable<Response>getNextPageObjects(@Path("next") String nextURL);
```

This is how the Response object would look like

[image]

You would have to then parse the headers and body from the observable

```
serviceClass.getNextPageObjects("next").flatMap(new Func1<Response, Observable<List<Objects>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<AuthState> call(Response response) {
         List<Header> headers = response.getHeaders();
         GsonConverter converter = new GsonConverter(new Gson());
         // you would have to change this to convert the objects to list
         List<Objects> list = converter.fromBody(response.getBody(),
                            YourClass.class);

        return Observable.from(list);
    }

}
```

Comment: Using this type of observable makes it difficult two zip calls together, at least from what I can tell. Is there any other way?

Comment: how about checking if response  isSuccessful()  ??

Comment: `Observable<Response<ResponseBody>>` this can give you both the response body and the header information. Therefore, if you're looking for a full response with the header and body use it.

Comment: For Kotlin you can use below code to read Header

 var mHeaders = it.headers()
mHeaders.get("Server")

Answer (score 3):

Let me spoiler this. You could intercept request and response as of ***OkHttp-2.2***. As on [OkHttp wiki](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki) says interceptors will not work in `Retrofit` with `OkUrlFactory`. You need to provide your `Client` implementation to execute `Retrofit` requests on this [custom Client](https://gist.github.com/NikolaDespotoski/246812ae6fa15d089b0a) and directly on `OkHttp`

Unfortunately, it is not out yet (soon).

```
public class ResponseHeaderInterceptor implements Interceptor {
  public interface ResponseHeaderListener{
     public void onHeadersIntercepted(Headers headers);
  }
  private ResponseHeaderListener mListener;
  public ResponseHeaderInterceptor(){};
  public ResponseHeaderInterceptor(ResponseHeaderListener listener){
     mListener = listener;
  }
  @Override public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
    if(mListener != null){
       mListener.onHeadersIntercepted(response.headers());
     }
    return response;
  }
```

Usage:

```
ResponseHeaderListener headerListener = new ResponseHeaderListener(){
 @Override
 public void onHeadersIntercepted(Headers headers){
     //do stuff with headers
 }
};
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
okHttpClient.interceptors().add(new ResponseHeaderInterceptor(headerListener));
RestAdapter.Builder restAdapterBuilder = new RestAdapter.Builder();
restAdapterBuilder.setClient(new OkHttpClient22(okHttpClient));
```

This is application interceptor and will be called only once.

Please note that I did all this by logic, I still don't have OkHttp-2.2. Just read about it [here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors). I'll remove some of this text when 2.2 is latest jar.

Alternatively, you can try to create custom client and with one interface deliver the response:

```
public class InterceptableClient extends OkClient {
    private ResponseListener mListener;
    public interface ResponseListener{
        public void onResponseIntercepted(Response response);
    }
    public InterceptableClient(){};
    public InterceptableClient(ResponseListener listener){
        mListener = listener;
    }
    @Override
    public retrofit.client.Response execute(Request request) throws IOException {
        Response response =  super.execute(request);
        if(mListener != null) //runs on the executor you have provided for http execution
            mListener.onResponseIntercepted(response);
        return response;
    }
}
```

**Edit:** OkHttp 2.2 has been [released](https://publicobject.com/2014/12/31/okhttp-2-2-has-interceptors/).