# Custom onNext() implementation for RxJava and Retrofit

Tags: retrofit, rx-android, abstraction

I'm using RxJava alongside Retrofit and I'm trying to find a really clean way of abstracting my API calls in such a way that I can minimize code in the Activity.

So far, I have something like this:

```
Observable<SomeObservable> combined =
            Observable.zip(firstObservable, secondObservable, SomeObservable::new);

    // Works but needs header parsing
    RxRestNetworker.performAsyncApiCall(combined, (returnData) -> {
        // onNext() implementation
    }, () -> hideSuggestionProgress());
```

The `RxRestNetworker` class looks like:

```
public class RxRestNetworker {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = RxRestNetworker.class.getCanonicalName();

    // Default error handling
    private static Action1<Throwable> mOnError = throwable -> {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, throwable.getMessage());
        throwable.printStackTrace();
    };

    /**
     * Perform the desired request with default error handling
     * @param observable
     * @param onAction
     * @param <T>
     * @return
     */
    public static <T> Subscription performAsyncApiCall(Observable<T> observable, Action1<? super  T> onAction, Action0 onComplete) {
        // Use default error handling
        return performAsyncApiCall(observable, onAction, mOnError, onComplete);
    }

    /**
     * Perform the desired request with some error handling OTHER than the default one
     * @param observable
     * @param onAction
     * @param onError
     * @param <T>
     * @return
     */
    public static <T> Subscription performAsyncApiCall(Observable<T> observable, Action1<? super T> onAction, Action1<Throwable> onError, Action0 onComplete) {
        return observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(onAction, onError, onComplete);
    }

}
```

So you can see I'm using the default `onError()` by calling the first `performAsyncApiCall` method.

Now this all works, but I need to access the headers of the response by getting access to the response object.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32488176/4284981) post claimed that I should wrap my response object and declare it like so in the API:

```
Observable<Response<SomeResponse>> getThings();
```

But I don't really care for that. It seems ugly and makes zipping observables like above a headache.

Ideally, I'd like to create an abstraction of the `onNext() Action1` argument that can by default log the headers and do anything else done for every API call, then pass the results of the call back to the caller. Am I going in the wrong direction with this?  Can somebody please help me find a way to abstract this in a very clean manner?